# Instead of using a "Select" dropdown menu, what else can/should I be using?

Tags: html

In the picture below, I have a basic client database; each client has a bunch of properties, and to avoid making each individual client "container" stretch (e.g.: 1000 properties would look funny), I decided to put their properties inside of a select box.

To me, it looks great (didn't style it yet); however, is it proper to use a select box just to hide information like I'm doing? Selecting an item (property/address) isn't meant to do anything at all.

Thanks!

[http://i.imgur.com/SgvL7Ab.png](https://i.imgur.com/SgvL7Ab.png)

[image: Select box example]

UPDATE:

It's been awhile, but I decided to use the html5 'details' tag, it looks fantastic; however, it does apparently have its browser limitations. I use it on a few pages, but the following is a basic example of how it looks:

[image: Using the Details tag]

Comment: You could just create a div with an explicit height and overflow:scroll set on it

Comment: That's actually not a bad idea. I'll give it go!

Comment: I think styling a select element would be the proper UX.

Comment: styling select boxes is very intermittently possible.  Most select boxes are OS controlled.  Also if you do not use native select box you lose the nice mobile functionality.  Shameless self blog plug http://matterickson.me/dropdowns_selectboxes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just create a div with an explicit height and overflow:scroll set on it

```
<style>
    .properties {
        display:inline-block;
        height:100px;
        overflow:scroll;
        width:300px;
        // etc

    }
</style>


<div class="properties">

</div>
```

But honestly, there is nothing wrong with leveraging default browser functionality like this unless it creates a counter-intuitive user experience. I think this may be on the edge of that as is but you know your product better than I do so the decision ultimately comes down to what you think is right for your users

Comment: I think I will stick with the Select box; however, reminding me that I could actually use a div with overflow scroll made me feel incredibly stupid hahaha, I didn't even consider it! 10 points for Gryffindor!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, what you are doing is perfectly fine, although there may be some misunderstandings by users.  A lot of people associate dropdowns with changing a value.

I might rather use a JS alert box, like this:

```html
<button onclick='javascript: alert("Phone: (123) 456-78910\nEmail: Someone@anemailprovider.com\nAddress: 1234 NW 465th Lane, St. Louis, Mo 123456")'>Click here for more information about me.</button>
```

The only downside of this is that you cannot change the style of the box.  You can style the button, though.

Hope this helps!